# Store entry with multiple apks won't show up on older api

Tags: android, apk, store

I have uploaded multiple apks to the google play store with different minimum api level. I'm able to install the app on a device that runs on api 26 but I can't find it with a device on api 23.

[Picture: apk with lower api is retained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJPa6.png)

Am I missing some settings? Can you see it?

[Store link: Shoggoth Rising](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.dreipol.shogothrising&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that android.hardware.camera.ar was in the feature list on both apks. Devices without ar support won't show up the app in the store. Unity automatically adds the feature unrelated if the ar core plugin is used or not.